# JSF primefaces editor loading file

Tags: file, jsf, primefaces, editor

I'm using jsf primefaces editor, i want to load a text file a value to it. 
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/editor.jsf

Please may i know if this is possible?

Comment: The `<p:editor>` expects a `String` value. Just lookup how to put content of a text file in a `String` using the normal Java means. This step is completely unrelated to JSF/PrimeFaces.

Comment: Yeah i think that is the way... will try